# Props is always undefined when using <Link> with react router, on every page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using `react-router-dom` and `Link` to pass props to other components, I intend to use these props on my `/details` route. However I can't seem to define the props, I've checked other questions and I'm using: 
`<Link to={{pathname:'/details', state: {Obj:this.state}}}>` to no avail:

`Home.js`

```
// this will be the home page that lists all the available leads

import React from 'react'
import {getAllLeads, getAllLeadsGraphQL} from '../../src/calls'
import List from './List'
import {LeadDetails} from './LeadDetails'
import {CreateLead} from './CreateLead'
import util from 'util'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){

  super(props)
  this.state = {
    dataType: "", // store the type of data for the type of operation that should be sent to the backend. For example "create" will have the data for creating data
    data: {},
    displayOptions: false,
    leads: [],
    selectedLead: null
    } 

    // have CRUD options that are displayed when user clicks on a lead. When on of the options are selected
    // display the appropriate fields
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.displayDetails = this.displayDetails.bind(this)
  }

  async handleChange(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    // use console.log here otherwise it won't show the desired value for state on the first click
    // this.setState({displayOptions: true}, () => console.log(this.state)) 
    // now get the details for each lead from backend

  }


  async displayDetails(dataType, selectedLead){
    selectedLead.contacted = JSON.stringify(selectedLead.contacted)
    this.setState({
      displayOptions: true,
      dataType: dataType,
      selectedLead: selectedLead
    }, () => console.log("options", this.state));

  };


  async componentDidMount() {
    var leads = await getAllLeads((data) => {return data});
    leads = JSON.parse(leads)
    this.setState({ leads });
    console.log("REF", leads)

    // GraphQL CALL
    // var leads = await getAllLeadsGraphQL(function(data){
    //   return data
    // })
    // leads = JSON.parse(leads)
    // leads = leads.all_leads
    // this.setState({ leads })
  }



  // <HomePage dataState={this.state}/>
  // then if the dataType isn't empty display the HTML for those fields
  // <Card Obj={this.state} displayDetails={this.displayDetails}/>
  render() {
    // when one of the leads is clicked, display options
    if(this.state.dataType === "detail" && this.state.displayOptions === true){
        console.log("DISPLAY Details",this.state.displayOptions)
        // Switch>
        // <Route path="/leads" component={Home}></Route>
        // </Switch>
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1> Details for {this.state.selectedLead["firstName"]}  {this.state.selectedLead["lastName"]} </h1>
            <LeadDetails Obj={this.state} />
          </div>
        )

    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1> Select lead  </h1>
            <List Obj={this.state} displayDetails={this.displayDetails}/>      
          <CreateLead/>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

`List.js>`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

    class List extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          showMenu: false,
        };

        this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
        this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
      }

    showMenu(leadObj){
        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log("SELECTED", leadObj)
        this.props.displayDetails('detail', leadObj)

    }

      closeMenu(event) {

        if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

          this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
          }); 

        }
      }

      handleClick(arg){
          console.log("HEREw", arg)
          this.props.updateOptions(arg)
          console.log(this.props.Obj)
      }

      render() {
        console.log("THIS PROPS HERE", this.props)
        return (  
          <div>
            {this.props.Obj.leads.map(lead => (
            <div>
<Link to={{pathname:'/details', state: {Obj:this.state}}}>
            <button key={lead.id} href={lead.first_name} onClick={()=>this.showMenu({"email":lead.email, "firstName":lead.first_name, 
            "lastName":lead.last_name, "contacted": lead.contacted, "updatedAt":lead.updated_At, "createdAt": lead.created_At})}>
                {lead.first_name} {lead.last_name} 
            </button>
</Link>
            </div>  
            ))}

          </div>
        );
      }
    }


    export default List
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from './components/Home'
import List from './components/List'
import {CreateLead} from './components/CreateLead'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/details" component={List} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateLead} />
        </Switch>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I can see the route object or whatever it is with the `location`, `history` etc

Comment: So what props are undefined? In what component are they undefined? How is *that* component being rendered? Please update your question to include the code you have an issue with.

Comment: can you share the component that you render at `/details`?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated it! The props I'm passing to <List> is undefined

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez updated it!

Comment: @CharlesSmith you have the correct answer from Zohaib

Comment: Well, where do you render `List` then? What do you pass it?

Comment: Is `List` not being rendered in `Home`? I just want to pass it the state from `Home`

Comment: Ah, you import it as `Cards`, and you don't pass any props to it.

Comment: Sorry I shouldve changed that naming. But am I supposed to also pass props in the `Cards` element? As I normally would?

Comment: Yes, if you want `Obj` to be defined in the render function, `<Card Obj={this.state} />`. It doesn't look like any Route component is rendering it, and it is not wrapped in a `withRouter` HOC.

Comment: In that case should I avoid using the `pathname` argument or is it better to just export my Component in the wrapper `withRouter`?

Comment: I'm not sure if that works, I use the wrapper and I'm getting the same error. It seems that Link will always pass through it's own props rather than the one I pass the conventional way

Comment: I think you've conflated `Link`'s and `Route`'s. Routes are what have [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props), and thus, access to `props.location.state`, links allow your to pass some "state" with the push to the new route. Can you update question with your `Router`?

Comment: In your Link component write {this.props.location.state.Obj.leads.map( lead => ( instead of {this.props.Obj.leads.map(lead => (

Comment: I see, okay thanks. But the problem remains, even using the answer from the other poster I get `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Check' of 'this.props.location.state' as it is undefined.`

Comment: Tried that before too @Zohaib, in the console I can see `state` is still undefined

Comment: i think we cant pass component's state object in to. this might be cause of error. static objects works fine like this  <Link to={{ pathname: '/details', state: { User: { name: 'abc' } } }}>

Comment: you are trying to pass object from state this might be reason of error <Link to={{pathname:'/details', state: {Obj:this.state}}}>

Comment: @CharlesSmith can you show the code where you render your Routes, that might be helpful.

Comment: Just added it, also I changed the name of `Card` to `List`

Comment: Okay I updated, also now `<List>`  is being passed props the conventional way `<List Obj={this.state} displayDetails={this.displayDetails}/>`

Answer (score 2):

You can paas data from `<Link />` component by passing object in to property and access in your child component.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/details', state: { Check: true } }}>
  <Card />
<Link>
```

Now you can access state object values in your details component.

```
const { Check } = this.props.location.state;
```

or

```
const Check = this.props.location.state.Check;
```

You can paas any data in state object and access in your Child component.
You can even paas object in state like this.

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: '/details', state: { User: { name: 'abc' } } }}>
  <Card />
 <Link>
```

and access

```
const userName = this.props.location.state.User.name;
```

See Official docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: This is, OFC, correct, assuming the component matched to path "/details" is mounted/rendered correctly with `Route`, or uses `withRouter` HOC, in order to be passed the route props.

Comment: Are you asking something?. Please elaborate.

Comment: OP **is** setting `Link` props correctly. I'm just pointing out your answer, while technically correct (it's not wrong), doesn't really answer the OP's question as it isn't know yet how the component is mounted/rendered to understand why any props would be undefined.

Comment: When I try this I get the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Check' of 'this.props.location.state' as it is undefined.`

Comment: No matter what the state is undefined

Answer (score 0):

From your most recent update I think your problem is that you're not wrapping your app with a Router

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from './components/Home'
import List from './components/List'
import {CreateLead} from './components/CreateLead'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/details" component={List} />
            <Route path="/create" component={CreateLead} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

You always need to wrap everything with a router, in your case, `BrowserRouter`.

After wrapping your app with the router you can log the props to verify your state is there.

```
console.log(this.props.location.state)
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue man, it's not defining the state. Even when I import my routers with the `withRouter` wrapper it's the same issue

Comment: Ill try the console log

Comment: This is the output of the the log : `location: {pathname: "/details", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}`

Comment: are you accessing that route by clicking the Link component?

Comment: I believe so? I'm clicking each link inside that map() function you see there

Comment: Would I need to place a Link inside the map() function?

Comment: I tried placing the Link element in the map()  and it successfully takes me to the details page when I click that link. But `state` is still undefined

Comment: why are you wrapping your `<List />` with the `<Link>` component? If you have made any update to your code please update your post so I can see the latest version of what you're working with.

Comment: I confused myself, it was wrong to do that since im not clicking list, I added `Link` to my map() ill update now

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Right now you're rendering `<Link>` inside of List, but that Link takes you to `/details` route, which renders your `List` component again. Explain what would you like to do and I'll try my best to help you.

Comment: The `/details` route should render my `LeadDetails` component. In my list component the state is changed (when you click the JSX wrapped in the `Link`), which my `home` component checks for then renders `LeadDetails`

Comment: I've got it closer to working, ive passed the object from `List` to `LeadDetails`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210510/discussion-between-edgar-henriquez-and-charles-smith).